Conflict Between Traefik Basic Auth and RabbitMQ Authentication
I'm encountering a conflict between RabbitMQ's authentication and Traefik's Basic Auth. After successfully passing Traefik's Basic Auth, I log in to RabbitMQ, but then Traefik prompts for Basic Auth again.
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.11.28-management-alpine
    container_name: rabbitmq
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=guest
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=guest
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.rabbitmq.rule=Host(`rabbitmq.${SERVICE_DOMAIN}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.rabbitmq.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.services.rabbitmq.loadbalancer.server.port=15672"
      - "traefik.tcp.services.ingress.loadbalancer.server.port=5672"
      - "traefik.http.routers.rabbitmq.middlewares=auth-rabbitmq"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.auth-rabbitmq.basicauth.users=${SERVICE_USER}"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.auth-rabbitmq.basicauth.removeheader=true"
    networks:
      - proxy

I configured RabbitMQ with Traefik Basic Auth. I expected to authenticate through Traefik once, then access RabbitMQ's management interface without further prompts. However, after passing Traefik's Basic Auth, I logged into RabbitMQ, and Traefik asked for authentication again.
